# what does the equals() exactly comparing when you using it to compare two objects?

Tags: java

here is the class I want to compare:

```
public class test
{
   private String str=null;
   private int integer=0;
   private double doubleNum=1.1; 
}
```

now I'm comparing it by instantiate two same classes

```
public class testEquals
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      test s1 = new test();
      test s2 = new test();
      System.out.print(s1.equals(s2));
   }
}
```

the result is

> > false

Comment: You havent overridden `equals`

Comment: @Reimeus he does not have to. Hes original question how `Object#equals` works

Comment: This depends on the implementation of equals() of the class of the object. Your example uses the default one, which is documented in the javadoc of Object. If you want to know how Strings are compared with equals(), look at the javadoc of String.equals(). Similarly for all the classes.

Answer (score 8):

Your `test` class didn't override `equals`, so it inherits [the method from `Object`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals(java.lang.Object)):

> The equals method for class Object implements the most discriminating possible equivalence relation on objects; that is, for any non-null reference values x and y, this method returns true if and only if x and y refer to the same object (x == y has the value true).

They aren't the same object, so `false` is returned.

Answer (score 2):

looking at Object.equeals() which is what you are calling, you will see that the default implementation is comparing the object using ==, which is basically comparing the address.

http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/java/lang/Object.java#149